# How to apply sales to custom order adjustment?

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce, plugin-craftcommerce3

Is it possible to apply a discount voucher to custom order adjustments? EG i want 5% off everything. I have two order adjustments, one is rush delivery and the other is an engraving fee.

At the moment i can only seem to apply it to the delivery and products in the order.